# 2x2 repeated measures ANOVA, significant interaction, all the pairwise comparisons significant

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, t-test, spss

I ran a 2 x 2 repeated measures ANOVA using SPSS. Both main effects and interaction were significant. Then I ran *t*-tests to locate significant comparisons, but all the comparisons are significant. I thought that in these cases, we only get significant main effects (graph shows two lines going down in parallel). Can anyone explain?